# how to change cruisecontrol head.xsl to reflect value dynamically from testng

Tags: selenium, cruisecontrol.net, testng

Currently I can hard code the header.xsl in cruisecontrol to show anything I want (e.g. browser type), but I'd like to also see the version of my app testng is running against. The version number is situated on the first page of my app under a div class. Is there a way to have cruisecontrol set the value into the header.xsl from grabbing the testng report?

Expected result:
I want to see on the cruisecontrol report info about my app like version #

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that version number ever output during the build process? Can you find it in the build log? If so it should be rather easy to figure out the xsl necessary to get it. If it isn't you would have to do a lot of customizing because they system expects to only display info inside the build log, statistics.csv, and report.xml files.

Comment: no it's not in the build log, but is it possible to use selenium to grab the value, store it in testng log and then have cruisecontrol grab it?

Comment: I do not know selenium, sorry, but that is the approach I would try. The other thing to try would be when the web site is built, save off the version number in a text file somewhere both projects could reach, then have your test simply read that file and echo it out, now it is in your build log. ;) gl